# Possible to add a "configuration" page to my custom timer job?

Tags: 2010, timer-jobs

I would like to have a page in the central admin that allows administrators to configure a few values for the my timer job.  Is there a way that I can do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Absolutely, I have done this myself very recently.

You can create an Application Page that sits in the ADMIN directory in the SharePoint Root Folder. You need to add a mapped folder in Visual Studio to do this.

You can then create a Custom Action which will add a link to your application page, within any area and section within Central Administration that you wish.

Here is the tutorial I followed on MSDN for this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798467.aspx

Also, the full reference implementation for a timer job with a config page:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798362.aspx

Comment: +1 as usual, you are the man James.  Any suggestions on how to access that value from the timer job?

Comment: :) I've added a link to my answer which is the tutorial I followed.

Comment: Here's the tutorial for the application page for a timer job: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798356.aspx There are links here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798362.aspx for the rest of the reference implementation.